# TCP Window Scaling in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, network-programming

I'm a beginner for network programming. I read some resources that I could find on the internet, where I came across TCP Window Scaling. As I understood, the scaling factor is negotiated when the connection is first established, in the SYN packet. So does this mean that TCP Window scaling cannot be set by the code that we would write for socket programming? Is it the operating system which does this? Say, in a windows environment, how does this happen and is there a way for us to manually/dynamically change it?

Comment: Why would you want to change the window size?

Comment: That is theoretical nice trick to check if the other side is aviable if you can put the window size to zero.

Comment: @Nick: it is only for learning purposes, I'm just understanding the concepts of TCP communication.

Comment: @rekire: can you please explain more what you meant by the comment? I'm pretty new to this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: The window size is a mechanismen of traffic control. If one side sets the window size to zero the communication will stop. In a senario with push notification you could theoretical send a message with zero bytes and will get a tcp notification that the package was recieved. That is a nice trick to check if the client is online without data traffic. To resume the communication the side which set the window size to zero has to set it back to a bigger value.

Comment: Nobody seems to have read the question. He didn't ask how to change the window siz. Hhe asked how to enable window scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe this can only be set at a global level. There is a registry setting for this under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` key.

It's called `GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize`. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957546.aspx

If what you actually mean is to change the size of the socket receive and transmit buffers then these can be changed using Winsock. See `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF`.

Comment: Well your answer is great but does not explain how to change the TCP windowsize for a connection/package.

Comment: @rekire. I don't believe this is possible using standard Winsock only at a global level. As you mention in your answer you can use WinCap.

Comment: I aggree with you it's almost impossible.

Comment: @Izza This doesn't answer your question, and it is mistaken. The socket receive buffer size determines the maximum window size. The registry entry above just provides the global maximum. For how to enable window scaling see my answer.

Comment: @rekire He didn't ask how to change the TCP windowsize. He asked about *scaling.*

Answer (score 4):

Window scaling is enabled automatically if you set a socket receive buffer size of more than 64k, via `setsockopt().`

As the window scaling negotiation happens during the connection handshake, you have to do that before connecting the socket. In the case of sockets accepted by a server via a listening socket, this is obviously impossible, so you have to do the apparently odd operation of setting the socket receive buffer size on the listening socket instead, from where it is inherited by all sockets accepted from it.

Comment: Interesting! Can you provide links?

Comment: @EJP: Any concrete proof/documentation for this?

Comment: It follows directly from RFCs 793 and 1323, and the *man* pages for Berkeley Sockets, but see also for example the Javadoc for [ServerSocket.setReceiveBufferSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize(int)).

Answer (score 0):

The window size of TCP packages are managed by the operation system. So far you cannot change that dynamically. For a static way to change the window size for the whole system see [Nicks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12387767/995926) answer.

There is just one very hard way: You WinCap there you can write out every TCP package you want. But that is a real pain.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He is asking how to enable window scaling, not how to alter the window size, although you are wrong about that too. The maximum window size is determined by the socket receive buffer size, per socket, not system wide. If you don't set it, there is a system wide default, of course.